# Under bash, how to extract two numbers by parsing a string

Tags: string, bash, numbers, extract

guys,

I searched around a lot but can't get a desired solution to my problem. So I have to post here.

I need to extract two numbers from a string, the string may or may not contain other numbers except these two I want to parse.

For instance, the strings may looks like :

> newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_3515
>
> snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_1185
>
> newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-5000_2522

So, what I want to extract are the numbers after "Int-" and "Exp-", which correspond to 300 and 10000 in the first and second string, 300 and 5000 in the third string.

Moreover, I need to use these two numbers for further analysis. That's is to say, I hope these two numbers can be assigned to two variables, rather just print them out, in a bash script, not a command line format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) there is way to do this whitout requirement of external tools (*forks*) like `sed`, `awk` or other:

```
i=0;
while read string ;do
    ((i++))
    int=${string#*Int-}
    int=(${int//[a-z_-]/ })
    exp=${string#*Exp-}
    exp=(${exp//[a-z_-]/ })
    var=(${string//[a-z_-]/ })
    printf "Line #%2d contain: Int: %6s, Exp: %6s in %2d values: <%s>\n" \
        $i "$int" "$exp" ${#var[@]} "${var[*]}"
  done <<<'
newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_3515

snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_1185

newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-5000_2522
'
Line # 1 contain: Int:       , Exp:        in  0 values: <>
Line # 2 contain: Int:    300, Exp:  10000 in  4 values: <5 300 10000 3515>
Line # 3 contain: Int:       , Exp:        in  0 values: <>
Line # 4 contain: Int:    300, Exp:  10000 in  3 values: <300 10000 1185>
Line # 5 contain: Int:       , Exp:        in  0 values: <>
Line # 6 contain: Int:    300, Exp:   5000 in  4 values: <5 300 5000 2522>
Line # 7 contain: Int:       , Exp:        in  0 values: <>
```

or filtering lines containing **both** *Exp-* and *Int-*:

```
i=0
while read string ;do
    if [ "$string" != "${string#*Int-*Exp-}" ];then
        ((i++))
        int=${string#*Int-}
        int=(${int//[a-z_-]/ })
        exp=${string#*Exp-}
        exp=(${exp//[a-z_-]/ })
        var=(${string//[a-z_-]/ })
        printf "Line #%2d contain: Int: %6s, Exp: %6s in %2d values: <%s>\n" \
            $i "$int" "$exp" ${#var[@]} "${var[*]}"
      fi
  done <<<'
newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_3515

snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_1185

newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-5000_2522
'
Line # 1 contain: Int:    300, Exp:  10000 in  4 values: <5 300 10000 3515>
Line # 2 contain: Int:    300, Exp:  10000 in  3 values: <300 10000 1185>
Line # 3 contain: Int:    300, Exp:   5000 in  4 values: <5 300 5000 2522>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your code ! Although I solely picked up these four lines : "int = ... int = ... exp = ... exp = ... ", they satisfied quite well on my requirements. Again, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Using bash regular expression matching

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ _Int-([[:digit:]]+)_Exp-([[:digit:]]+) ]]; then
        printf "int=%d; exp=%d\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done <<END
newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_3515
snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_1185
newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-5000_2522
END
```

```
int=300; exp=10000
int=300; exp=10000
int=300; exp=5000
```

---

removing the while loop

```
str=newSetupSL5_snolab_Int-300_Exp-10000_3515
if [[ $line =~ _Int-([[:digit:]]+)_Exp-([[:digit:]]+) ]]; then
    printf "int=%d; exp=%d\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments ! Maybe I didn't state clearly enough in my message. In fact, every time I only need to handle one string, not a file contains many strings. So, do you think it's possible to change the code from "read line" to another code which can read string ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can make it with this look-behind expression:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Int-)\d+|(?<=Exp-)\d+' file
300
10000
300
10000
300
5000
```

To see it more clear, note how it fetches number just after `Int-`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Int-)\d+' file
300
300
300
```

And then it is just a matter of adding the other condition with the `|`.

---

### Update

[Glenn Jackman's great suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399238/under-bash-how-to-extract-two-numbers-by-parsing-a-string#comment28753888_19399302) improves the output:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Int-)\d+|(?<=Exp-)\d+' file | paste - - | while read n1 n2
> do
> echo "int=$n1 ext=$n2"
> done
int=300 ext=10000
int=300 ext=10000
int=300 ext=5000
```

---

### On OP's comment

> @fedorqui and glenn jackman : Thanks a lot for your codes - your code
>   looks very nice. However, as mentioned in my original message, I
>   actually need a line of code to deal with a string, rather a file. And
>   this code line(s) should be integrated into my script. Do you know how
>   to replace the "file" with "$string" ? Thanks a lot !

You can do it as follows:

```
grep -Po '(?<=Int-)\d+|(?<=Exp-)\d+' <<< "$string"
```

Comment: and to iterate over them: `grep -oP  '(?<=Int-)\d+|(?<=Exp-)\d+' file | paste - - | while read n1 n2; do ...; done`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. The `paste - -` goes directly to my cheat sheet, very nice!

Comment: @fedorqui and glenn jackman : Thanks a lot for your codes -  your code looks very nice. However, as mentioned in my original message, I actually need a line of code to deal with a string, rather a file. And this code line(s) should be integrated into my script. Do you know how to replace the "file" with "$string" ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @user2740039 you can do something like `$ grep -Po '...' <<< "$string"` instead

Comment: @fedorqui and glenn jackman : Every time, there only exists one string need to be parsed. But the shapes of string are variant.

Comment: @fedorqui, Very good improvement on your code. Thanks ! BTW, for the script version of your code would be : _italic_ `grep -Po "(?<=Int-)\d+|(?<=Exp-)\d+" <<< $filename_without_suffix | paste - - | while read n1 n2`.

Comment: @user2740039 yes! And it is better if you wrap the variable within double quotes like `grep -Po "(?<=Int-)\d+|(?<=Exp-)\d+" <<< "$filename_without_suffix" | paste...`

Comment: @fedorqui, Oh, really ? How I can benefit from wrap $string into " " ? Or, if I don't do that, what kind(s) of potential risk I need to deal with ?

Comment: It preserves format. For example, for the expression `awk '{print $1}' <<< $d` try to execute with and withoud `""` on `$d` if `d=hello (new line) bye`.